# How to define multiple throttle in django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

The documentation of django_Rest_framework states:

> Multiple throttles can also be used if you want to impose both burst throttling rates, and sustained throttling rates. For example, **you might want to limit a user to a maximum of 60 requests per minute, and 1000 requests per day**.

However, it is not explained how to implement a situation like it.

I've tried something like this but it didn't work

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '100/day',
        'user': ['30/minute', '1000/day']
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work. What makes you think it doesn't ?

Comment: I've tried it and it raises en exception: `'list' object has no attribute 'split'`. I'm using a non-up-to-date version of the app: `djangorestframework==3.6.4`. I cannot change it the site is running in django 1.8.

Answer (score 15):

It is possible but it is necessary to define multiple limits, one for each time unit.

1. First you define in the settings all the limits you need, for example no more than 30 per minute and no more than 1000 per day.

```py
        REST_FRAMEWORK = {
          'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
                    'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
              'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
          ),
          'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
              'anon': '100/day',
              'user_min': '30/minute',
              'user_day': '1000/day',
          }
        }
```

2. You add Throttling classes as subclasses of `UserRateThrottle` with the scopes you defined:

```py
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle

class UserMinThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
             scope = 'user_min'
```

3. Finally on the APIView you set as throttle_classes the classes with the limits you defined on the previous step.

```py
class YourAPIView(APIView):
     throttle_classes = [
          UserMinThrottle,
          UserDayThrottle
     ]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a good question, and I had a little more complex situation since I wanted to apply multiple throttles to only one method of my ViewSet (create/POST in my case).

So first I figured out how to apply throttles only for specic methods in ViewSets and I found this post: http://www.pedaldrivenprogramming.com/2017/05/throttling-django-rest-framwork-viewsets/

and since `ViewSet` inherits `APIView`, I made it so I'll append the **`APIView` `throttle_classes` list**.

```
import myprojectname.throttles as throttles # throttles.py

class MyFooViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):


# Only throttle specific methods
def get_throttles(self):
    if self.action in ['create']:
        # Apply these throttle classes 
        self.throttle_classes.append(throttles.FooThrottleBurst)
        self.throttle_classes.append(throttles.FooThrottleSustained)
        # ...
```

**throttles.py** looks like this (nothing special, just like https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#userratethrottle)

```
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle

class FooThrottleBurst(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'mynamespace.burst'

class FooThrottleSustained(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'pricereport.sustained'
```

And those rates are defined in settings.py of course:

```
# ... some example values
'mynamespace.burst':        '3/minute',
'mynamespace.sustained':    '5/hour',
# ...
```

After testing with Postman I was able to do 3 successfull POSTs in a minute (4. obviously throttled). After waiting for ~60 secs and making new requests, the 'sustained' throttling rule got applied (5/hour) and DRF returned me this:

```
{
    "detail": "Request was throttled. Expected available in 3538 seconds."
}
```

I don't know about OP's situation, but I wanted to share my approach

Answer (score 2):

You can not have a list of rates for the `UserRateThrottle`.

According to the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#userratethrottle) you have to configure a scope to allow several rates.

In your case, it'll be:

```py
class BurstRateThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'burst'

class SustainedRateThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'sustained'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'example.throttles.BurstRateThrottle',
        'example.throttles.SustainedRateThrottle'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '100/day',
        'burst': '60/min',
        'sustained': '1000/day'
    }
}
```